# Custom column in Django users profile

Tags: python, django

I want to add custom column in Django admin, on Users (`/auth/user/`) section.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

And in **admin.py** I have this code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Custom fields'

class CustomUser(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )
    list_diplsay = ('birthday')

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(CustomUser, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUser)
```

I've read here that `list_display` should do all the work, but in my case it doesn't work. I don't see any changes in my admin panel since I've added that line.

Where is the problem? Thanks!

**Edit:** Fixed by changing `list_diplsay` with `list_display`. Now I get this: `type object 'User' has no attribute 'birthday'`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo: `list_diplsay` should be `list_display`. You should probably also add a trailing comma to your list value: `('birthday',)`. This ensures you end up with a tuple and not a single value.

**Edit:**

Since the `birthday` field doesn't belong to the `User` you'll have to add a method to look it up in your admin class:

```
class CustomUser(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('birthday',)

    def birthday(self, obj):
        return obj.profile.birthday
```

(I have only shown the relevant parts of the admin class; your existing `inlines` etc. should stay.)

Comment: You should use list for that purpose. It was initially designed to save memory but now it is irrelevant. `=['birthday']`

Comment: Yes, that would probably work too. We don't actually know what version of Django the OP is using.

Comment: Now I get this: `type object 'User' has no attribute 'birthday'`. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @Chris, yes. Thank you!